# Find calls to Dojo and Mootools using grep or similar

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, mootools

I have inherited a project that uses Dojo, Mootools and JQuery and loads all three libraries on almost every page. Since this is a Drupal project, which uses JQuery as the default library, I'd like to keep JQuery and convert the Dojo and Mootools parts to JQuery if possible. I believe that it is using the following versions (see my comment reply to Christophe)

- JQuery 1.5.1
- Mootools 1.2.5.
- Dojo 1.6.1

Right now I'm just trying to identify where Mootools and Dojo are used. Ideally, I'd like to find a regex that

- gives hits on calls to Mootools or Dojo but not JQuery (or filters them to some degree)
- errs on the side of false positives

Just as a quick check I ran a search with this regex: `(\$\(|[Mm]ootool|[Dd]ojo)`

Of course, that captures most calls to JQuery, but just to get a sense of how many files I'd have to look at. I got 5913 matches in 258 files

If I search only on `\$\(` I get 4081 matches in 221 files. These are probably overwhelmingly JQuery, but just trying to figure a good way to narrow do the number of instances I have to look at.

Comment: Which versions of dojo/Mootools? For example dojo 1.7+ is quite different from dojo 1.6-

Comment: Mootools file is mootools-1.2.5-core-yc.js so I guess 1.2.5
Dojo - I'm guessing 1.6.1 because I find this in the dojo.xd.js file: `dojo.version={major:1,minor:6,patch:1`
Thanks Christophe

Comment: also, mootools is prototypical. calls on $ won't matter all that much - you need to worry about methods called on things like Array, String, Function etc as they won't get caught. also see http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/firebug-tip-log-function-calls/ - you can log function calls now in FB. if you want to trap all mootools $ calls, then you want to log calls to `document.id` not $. mootools won't take over the $ if its already assigned when it loads.

Comment: Thanks Dimitar. I am assuming that the $ is reserved for the JQuery namespace as JQuery is loaded on every page and definitely is using that. So as you say, I don't think mootools should be using it. Thanks also for the idea of logging calls - the only problem with that is I will have to load every page on the site to know what gets called where, right? I'm trying to find a method that would not require that (this is a pretty big site). Thanks for the idea though - I could visit a sample and see what that reveals.

Comment: PS: load order is dojo, jquery, mootools.

Answer (score 0):

Will be easier for you to delete the include for those libraries and go page by page with chrome/firefox and check for errors, than to develop something to find calls to MooTools.

Another approach. Modify the Mootools/Dojo libraries to log each time they are used, and who/where they are used. A simple ajax call to server can be enough.

Comment: That's my backup, but the site has over 1000 pages, so it's a fairly long process to do it that way and since I don't actually know the site that well, I might not notice that some Javascript effect has stopped working. In others words, if the dojo feature degrades gracefully, how will I know? So I will not only have to visit every page, I will have to carefully compare functionality (hover effects, link clicks and so on) on the live site and the dev site to see what's missing. That's a huge QA task.

Comment: Well...That is the magnitude of your task.

Comment: Yes, yes it is... I may need to charge more ;-)